# Unity3D failing to execute Newtonsoft Json code

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I just updated the way my code loads a file:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(Data.BaseDir, "entities.txt");
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
   string tempJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
   {
      TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
   };
   IList parsedEntities = (IList)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(tempJson, settings);
   foreach (Entity e in parsedEntities)
   {
      //e.Initialise();
      Map.Get(e.Coord).Entity = e;
   }
}
```

This code compiles but then has a runtime exception in the Unity 5 editor.
(log below)
This code happens to be common with my editor which is a windows forms project and it runs fine when compiled by visual studio.
My `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` says that it is version 7.

Is this a problem with the Unity compiler?
Are certain parts of Newtonsoft Json DLL uncompatible with unities version of .Net?
How should I write this to be compatible with Unity?

**Log:**

> JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'MO1Common'.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.GetTypeFromTypeNameKey (TypeNameKey typeNameKey)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder+TypeNameKey,System.Type].AddValue (TypeNameKey key)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder+TypeNameKey,System.Type].Get (TypeNameKey key)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.BindToType (System.String assemblyName, System.String typeName)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type& objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract& contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.String qualifiedTypeName)
>   Rethrow as JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'MO1.Definitions.Entities.Charactor, MO1Common'. Path '[0].$type', line 1, position 57.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type& objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract& contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.String qualifiedTypeName)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type& objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract& contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue, System.Object& newValue, System.String& id)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id)

Comment: Have you tried referencing the missing assembly (MO1Common.dll) to the project?

Comment: Ok. Talking to a senior programmer I now understand the basic problem. Unity does not include the same Assembly libraries that exist in my Visual studio project. It just grabs all of the classes and creates one assembly library. I was advised to get around this by using "IfDefs". I'll post the answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this code:

```
#If Unity
tempJson = tempJson.Replace("MO1Common", "Assembly-CSharp")
#EndIf
```

This requires adding the IfDef "Unity" to the unity project.

The problem is that Json.Net was trying to reference the assembly library "MO1Common" which I had set up in visual studio, however, Unity compiles all of the classes in its "scripts" folder into one default assembly library called "Assembly-CSharp". Simply replacing the name of the assembly library in the Json string when the code is being compiled by Unity fixes this problem.